# Counting the number of files in, and below a directory in Linux C

Tags: c, linux

I would like to know how to count the number of files in a directory and files below the directory using C in Linux.
I try to search for it and all I got is only counting the number of files in a directory without counting the file below the directory.

Comment: What kind of research have you made? If you try a few searches in your favorite search engine, what do you find then? There are plenty of tutorials and examples all over the Internet.

Comment: Programming is not just ask for the solution on the internet. Break the whole problem down into simple pieces that you can solve. For example, how do you tell whether an entry is a directory or a regular file?

Comment: *"without counting the file below the directory"* - What does that mean?

Comment: Where is your code? Without seeing your code, all we can say is you did something wrong. Read this: [ask] and this: [mcve]

Comment: @klutt he probably wants to count the number of files in a directory including all files in all subdirectories.

Comment: Google _linux list directories recursively_

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you are looking for a way to recursively search subdirectories. The utility you are looking for is called `dirent` which allows you to list files in a directory. Here's the manage for the POSIX version of `dirent`: https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man0/dirent.h.0p.html

Then what you probably want to do is have a recursive function that lists all subdirectories returned by `dirent` until all branches have been counted.

One word of warning is that you will get `.` (the current directory) and `..` (the parent directory) while listing and will need to exclude them.

Comment: I propose to use `fts.h` or `ftw.h` that should be present on many systems.